# Google Cloud Armor - missing default rule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I've created a cloud armor security policy but it does not have a default rule. I am confused because the documentation contradicts with this.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/securityPolicies

> A list of rules that belong to this policy. There must always be a default rule (rule with priority 2147483647 and match "*"). If no rules are provided when creating a security policy, a default rule with action "allow" will be added.

```
$ gcloud beta compute security-policies describe healthcheck
---
creationTimestamp: ''
description: ''
fingerprint: ...
id: '.....'
kind: compute#securityPolicy
labelFingerprint: .....
name: healthcheck
rules:
- action: deny(404)
  description: Block requests to /health
  kind: compute#securityPolicyRule
  match:
    expr:
      expression: request.path.matches('/health')
  preview: false
  priority: 1000
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/....
```

Based on my tests, the default behaviour seems to be `Allow`. Is this default rule hidden or am I missing something?
[image]

The rule was created with Terraform but I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies in the fact that there are different ways to create a Cloud Armor policy. For example, if you create a policy through the Cloud Console, you are required to choose the default rule type prior to creating the policy.

In your case, the policy was created using Terraform. Terraform will create a policy in effectively the same way as if you were to use gcloud commands from the Cloud Shell. Using something like Terraform or using gcloud commands will permit a Cloud Armor policy to be created **without** a default rule specified.

If a Cloud Armor policy is created without a rule specified (default or otherwise), then an “Allow” rule will be automatically added. This is the behavior documented in the REST resource [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/securityPolicies) you shared. One thing to take note of, it may take a few minutes before the default “Allow” rule is visible. In my testing it took at least 2 minutes minimum to be visible in the Console and through:

```
gcloud compute security-policies describe [POLICY_NAME]
```

Typically during Cloud Armor policy creation, a default rule is specified with the desired behavior ([step # 2](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#create-example-policies)). The example you have shared appears to not have updated in the console completely, thus does not show the default “Allow” rule. However, based on the description you provided for your setup, a default “Allow” rule would have been applied during the policy creation by Terraform.

You can always choose to change the behavior of the default rule from “Allow” to “Deny-404” (or “Deny-502”), using the command:

```
gcloud compute security-policies rules update 2147483647 --security-policy [POLICY_NAME]  --action "deny-404"
```

(2147483647 is the default rule priority, max int32)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This default rule seems to be there but it is invisible for me. A few hours passed and I can not see it in the web ui, using gcloud or even the API explorer - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/securityPolicies/get

Comment: Also, I don't think the documentation is accurate. 
`There must always be a default rule (rule with priority 2147483647 and match "*")`

Well, I can't see it. Maybe it is there but the API and the webui tells me nothing about it. This is confusing.

`If no rules are provided when creating a security policy, a default rule with action "allow" will be added.`

Again confusing. I did provide a rule. It was not a rule with priority 2147483647 but it was still a rule.

Comment: I completely understand that the current state of the docs is confusing. In your case the default rule is going to be there. As to why it is not being displayed could be an issue worth [reporting](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui?_ga=2.20012920.-1551759501.1572871535) as an [issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/concepts/issues). It is also possible that something in how Terraform created the CA policy is causing this display issue. Point-in-context: the testing I did was done directly in the console, I was not using Terraform.